# How to retain or avoid to loose data when I switch between two components in Angular4

Tags: angular

I have a parent component, contains four tabs, each individual components. If use [hidden], then on switching between components I do not loose data, but when I use *ngIf, I loose data which I filled inside input values of the component. How can we avoid to loose data ?

Comment: keep the data in the service/model/controller and not in the template

Comment: You can create a service with properties containing data you want and inject it to your component.

Comment: Why can't you use [hidden] then?

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you use `[hidden]` the component containing the data isn't destroyed, it's just not displayed. When you use `ngIf`the component is destroyed, and so is you data.

To avoid this you can use a service to keep track of your data. A service is a class that can strore your data, and even when all components are destroyed, the service will still have the data.

A service could be as simple as this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
    someDataYouWantToKeep:string = "data"
    someOtherDataYouWantToKeep:number = 1
}
```

Then in your component you can use it like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleService } from '<path to file>';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-setup',
    templateUrl: './setup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./setup.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private service: ExampleService) { }


    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.service.someDataYouWantToKeep)
        this.service.someOtherDataYouWantToKeep = 2
    }
}
```

In the constructor you can inject your component with `private service: ExampleService` and then use it with `this.service`.

Answer (score 0):

As @mika said, if you want to avoid losing your data you have two options :

- Do not use the `*ngIf` directive and prefer the `[hidden]`
- Save your data somewhere using the angular `ngOnDestroy` hook. This solution may cause performance issue tho, depending on how you save it (local storage, database, ...)